# QR-Codes of Temial-Teamachine

Tags: encodings

I have a tea-machine that reads QR-Codes and brews the tea accordingly. I want to generate my own codes.

I have the following codes (and more):

[image]

Copy/Paste of the C-Column

```
L7UMQRQCQAZBD
OYXPVAANAB4ZE
K4BCLQEFABBRE
F5IKJLYGABSJE
```

I tried a few different decoding mechanisms, but I didn't get any readings that would make sense to me.

I expect to get numbers for the time and temperature brewing. The name of tee. The number of times the same tee can be used to brew…

**Edit:**

All the codes as text:

```
VORWERK2AE4L7UMQRQCQAZBDERMYRTHWFKD7CM7PKMBOVEAUNE5WNISNWAIZT74WOLVSSHNSRUIHUWGKFUWKTNXXKI
VORWERK2AE4OYXPVAANAB4ZEER3V2QO4WL6DZGBPBIJWY3AOLKJRXNICEWXVGO6CEKNCKJHFPUPTB3R3EG5YTFTQQE
VORWERK2AE4K4BCLQEFABBREESWJ5KYBTINVAZWZ4SQ5AQUWFAZO3UPYAKOLO2HRIJNFNGXENAW3QU5IXRSKO5BFMI
VORWERK2AE4F5IKJLYGABSJEETKQTQVEY73L4SOLWW5P5NLB355G6BVHINON755S6ADUEBXUV3AFW2JQOWGCHT6CME
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RE.SE! Please include *all* text as text (styled as code if needed) instead of as an image, it'll be easier to manipulate and work with samples that way.

Comment: For reverse engineering without inspecting the software you need more samples. But even with more samples you may need a lot of tries before you are able to identify the correct algorithms and parameters. Check also reversing projects of devices from the same manufacturer. But in the end having a real firmware for reversing will save you much time.

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for: D I only scanned a 10 pack of red berry tea and you can see that even the marked area is always a bit different. NNX, NLX, NJX ..... here a variety as [codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLsbO.jpg) VORWERK2AE4NNXNZLQOABOZKETESBPTW3HNXITX55IXE4KQ7BT2I6Q5V2BDN7AOLUMWSQVLRI7WWWS4XSHANQZCO3M VORWERK2AE4NLXNZLQOABOZKESRYZSM4ZIUIVBUUDE6SBIVRNAFULFXBLLM7GNRZHL7EVWLOFHVWXVEBBEIBH3XCDA VORWERK2AE4NJXNZLQOABOZKEROUGUS7AMCX7557OJOEDQUHYZ4RPFAAIXW257QTULKSTP254FYP3HRDX5HR66MDQM VORWERK2AE4NHXNZLQOABOZKERFXN7N

Comment: I can provide you with "used" sample data if you want

Comment: I still don't know how to do this. I tried all algos I could find.